# AngularJS 1.5.6 controller not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

it's me again with another really simple question. I'm running Angular 1.5.6 and the controller doesn't seem to work in the way I would expect it to. In the below, {{ control.helo }} doesn't give me anything and I'm really not sure why.

```
<html ng-app="simplifiedExample">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="appController as control">
        {{ control.hello }}
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And in the controllers/controller.js I have the following:

```
var app = angular.module('simplifiedExample', []);

app.controller('appController', function () {
    this.hello = "Helloooo";
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Controller link is definitely correct, as I put a console.log("Test") in that file, and it got logged properly.

I also moved the controller declaration in the index.html file and nothing changed.

I also tried different CDNs and versions of Angular - same results.

I tried all of the above additionally on a CentOS 7 VM (I'm running Windows 10 on my computer), reproduced the issue on the VM too.

FINAL EDIT: Guys, I'm completely and utterly retarded. I had spelled "controller" as "contoller" in my app, which is obviously a typo. Everything works properly. Sorry for bothering and upvotes for everyone whose time I wasted. :(

Comment: Not reproducible. Posted code is okay, something about your setup.

Comment: Try `app.controller('appController', function ($scope) { $scope.hello = 'Hello'; });` Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: Tushar, I tried your version too, still no errors in the console and no output on the page. Dfsq, I'll power up a VM and try it on a second environment and will let you know in a bit.

Comment: Don't let me know :) This errors are very easy to fix if you open console and read error message, which has explanation what you did wrong. As for the code you posted - it's okay. My guess is that you have 404 of controller.js.

Comment: I mentioned I checked the console and there are no errors. Additionally when I added a console.log in controller.js, it got logged to the console properly, so it's not that :(

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController as control">
     //{{control.id}}
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('appController', function () {
    var control = this;
    control.id = "someValue";    
});
```

for more info [read this](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with below controller code :

```
var app = angular.module('simplifiedExample', []);
app.controller('appController', function () {
    var control = this;
    control.hello = "Helloooo";
});
```

Comment: So what? you posted exact same code as OP has posted. Not only original code is **correct**, but your version is **exactly** the same and hence can't change anything.